# Why does InnoDB have its own parser and server connection modules if MySQL has its own modules for completing those tasks?

Tags: mysql, innodb

It is my understanding that MySQL creates an execution plan from a SQL query, and then uses innodb (or any other storage engine) to execute the plan. If this is the case, then why does the innodb storage engine have its own parser, server main program, and user-session modules? It looks as if InnoDB could run on its own as a fully functional DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB began as an independent company in 1995. The founder wanted to create a standalone RDBMS server.

It wasn't until 2000 that InnoDB began working closely with MySQL, and by March 2001 they announced the InnoDB Table Handler, which allowed MySQL to delegate work to the storage engine.

But InnoDB wanted to support some features that MySQL did not support:

- FOREIGN KEY constraints
- Proprietary table options
- Transactions

MySQL wanted to allow InnoDB and other storage engines to implement their own features too. So they allowed the storage engine layer to perform their own SQL parsing. There are a number of features (like CHECK constraints) that are validated for syntax by the MySQL storage-independent layer, without implementing the semantics. It's up to the storage engine to perform extra parsing and implement those features.

There have also been cases where the InnoDB storage engine wanted to implement features that had no SQL support at the higher level.

For example, the InnoDB monitor, to output periodic troubleshooting data to the server's error log, could be enabled not by sensible syntax like `SET ENGINE INNODB MONITOR=ON` or something like that, but by creating a table with a special name:

```
CREATE TABLE innodb_monitor (a INT) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

It doesn't matter which schema you create this table in, nor what columns you put in it. It doesn't need any rows of data. The name itself is special to InnoDB, and it's a signal to start logging monitor data to the log. Just so they didn't have to implement a new configuration option or SQL syntax!

In later versions of MySQL, you can enable the monitor in a less hacky way with `SET GLOBAL innodb_status_output=ON`.